# How to insert 1 or 0 in Sql Server for bit type field if checkbox is checked?

Tags: c#, sql-server, checkbox, bit

I am trying to insert 1 or 0 in my SQL Server Database, and my data type is "bit".
I have tried doing this but it says incorrect syntax near where-

```
dt=g1.ExecDB( insert into tbl ("check1,check2,check3") values('"
            + Convert.ToByte(check1.Checked) + "','"
            + Convert.ToByte(check2.Checked) + "','"
            + Convert.ToByte(check3.Checked) + "' ) )
              where loginname = '"+Session["log"].ToString() + "'"
            ) ;
```

Please Guide me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: reflowed code. left syntax errors intact.

Comment: Never, ever concatenate data values to the query like that, **always** use parametrized queries.

Comment: Since your SQL isn't working, go to a SQL command prompt (such as in SQL Management Studio) and enter the command directly. It's much easier to debug that way than by going through extra layers in your application code.

Also, echoing what Alejandro says. The client-side technique you're using is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. What if someone changes the name of the "log" session variable to something like:

`'; delete from tbl; --`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the name of your checkboxes inside the sql string cannot work, and of course neither calling Convert.ToByte on them. In this way you simple insert inside a string the name of your controls and the name of a function that should convert their values. But of course this is only an invalid SQL command for the sql parser of your database.

Instead you should try to resolve your problem creating a valid SQL command from your C# code. This is an initial possible solution to your problem

```
dt=g1.ExecDB("insert into tbl (check1,check2,check3) values(" + 
             (check1.Checked ? "1" : "0") + ", " + 
             (check2.Checked ? "1" : "0") + ", " + 
             (check3.Checked ? "1" : "0") + 
             ") where loginname='"+Session["log"].ToString()+"'");
```

but there is a big problem with the concatenation of `Session["log"]`.
Concatenating string values (probably setup by user input) to form a sql command is a very bad practice because it is vulnerable to [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). So a change to the `ExecDB` to receive a list of parameters is mandatory.

I suggest  to change your ExecDB to something like this

```
public int ExecDB(string query, List<SqlParameter>parameters = null)
{
     using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connString))
     using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
     {
         cn.Open();
         if(parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
             cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
         return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
 }
```

and call it with

```
List<SqlParameter> ps = new List<SqlParameter>();
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@login", Session["log"].ToString());
ps.Add(p);
dt=g1.ExecDB("insert into tbl (check1,check2,check3) values(" + 
             (check1.Checked ? "1" : "0") + ", " + 
             (check2.Checked ? "1" : "0") + ", " + 
             (check3.Checked ? "1" : "0") + 
             ") where loginname=@login", ps);
```

the `List<SqlParameter>` parameter passed to ExecDB is optional, thus, if you have any code where the call to ExecDB doesn't need a parameter collection you could leave your code as is now.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Steve. Your suggestion was very helpful. Thanks a ton brother :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

1. Your C# code sample won't even compile.
2. Your constructing dynamic sql that is susceptible to a SQL injection attack
3. Your SQL `insert` query is syntactically invalid and would throw an error if you got your code to compile.

Assuming that those are corrected, the CLR maps SQL Server's `bit` datatype to/from `bool` (aka `System.Boolean`). So...

Try something like this:

```
const string @insertQuery = @"
  insert tbl ( check1 , check2 , check3 )
  select @p1 , @p2 , @p3
  where loginname = @login
  " ;

using ( SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection() )
using ( SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
{

  cmd.CommandText = insertQuery ;
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@p1"    , check1.Checked ) ;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@p2"    , check2.Checked ) ;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@p3"    , check2.Checked ) ;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@login" , (string) Session["log"] ) ;

  conn.Open();
  int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ;
  conn.Close() ;

  bool success ;
  if      ( rowsAffected == 0 ) success = false ;
  else if ( rowsAffected == 1 ) success = true ;
  else throw new InvalidOperationException() ;

  return success ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Nicholas. Your suggestion was also very appropriate and useful :-)
Thanks a ton :-)

Answer (score 0):

Inserting bit value in the database table from the c#:

Use sql parameter like this:

SqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@check1", Convert.ToBoolean(0))