# String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. Can`t understand why?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I know the issue and I searched online. I know that this exception is thrown when my value length is greater than the length defined in the SQL Server table.

This is my C# code:

```
using (SqlCommand cmdInsertUser = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Accounts] VALUES (@username, @password, @email, @fullname, @money, @active, @activationCode, @registrationDate);", con))
{
    Random random = new Random();
    const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    activationCode = (Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 6).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray()).ToString();

    con.Open();

    cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtSignUpUsername.Text);
    cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtSignUpPassword.Text);
    cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtSignUpEmail.Text);
    cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", txtSignUpFullName.Text);
    cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@money", Convert.ToInt32(txtSignUpMoney.Text));
    cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@active", 0);
    cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@activationCode", activationCode);
    cmdInsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registrationDate", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

    cmdInsertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

This is my SQL Server table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts] 
(
    [Id]               INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Username]         VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    [Password]         VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    [Email]            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [FullName]         VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Money]            INT         NOT NULL,
    [Active]           BIT         NOT NULL,
    [ActivationCode]   VARCHAR(6)  NOT NULL,
    [RegistrationDate] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

The values that I enter:

- Username = daniel7
- Password = 123456
- Email = da************16@email.com (my real mail is given instead of *)
- FullName = Daniel Ohayon
- Money = 0
- Active = 0
- ActivationCode = something random with 6 chars
- RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()

PLEASE HELP ME!

Comment: I think the problem is probably with your Active column. This other question may help if the link above doesn't (see the second answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155483/how-to-insert-1-or-0-in-sql-server-for-bit-type-field-if-checkbox-is-checked

Comment: Stop the laziness. Don't use [addwithvalue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). In addition, there is more laziness with your insert statement. ALWAYS specify the column list for the insert statement. Why? Because someone might change the order and somone might add columns at a later date. Let's avoid additional work that may not be necessary. Actually defining your parameters may solve your issue.

Comment: And the column RegistrationDate **should not be varchar!!!** It should be date or datetime2 (with the appropriate precision).

Comment: Are you sure Activation Code passing 6 characters. Put break point and check?

Comment: @hatchet thanks for the reply. I read this questions and unfortunately they didnt help me. I even tried to change the Active column from bit to int and insert 0 and it gave the same exception... :\ any other suggestions?

Comment: @ShakeerHussain You are right! the code is giving me System.Char[] instead of a real code.
Do you know why? it should work

Comment: ToString returns the name of the type when its not overloaded. An array does not overload that method. Use string.Concat or string.Join to build a string from your array

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `activationCode`, from the `Watch Window`? _Please check, don't guess._

Comment: Some other tips, don't store passwords at all (unless you must use them to authenticate against 3rd party service), hash them with a salt (google it if you don't know what that means). Also, don't store dates as text, store them as dates, this will make it much much easier to handle.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like your issue stems from this line of code:

```
activationCode = (Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 6).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray()).ToString();
```

This will return the name of the item, as this is an array object, not a six-digit character count you're probably expecting.

You can try using:

```
activationCode = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 6).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray())
```

instead.